# My for i in range loop is only iterating for once, I need to iterate it 19 times to create separate models

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:
There are 19 types of Products and I need to create seperate models for each of them.
The loop iterates for i == 1. But then exits the loop.

```
 for i in range(1,20):
   dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
   scaler = MinMaxScaler()
   df_result = df_result[df_result['Product'] == i]
   x = df_result[feature_colsx]
   y = df_result[feature_colsy]
   try:
      x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1,train_size=.80)
      x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
      x_test = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)
      dtc.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
      y_pred = dtc.predict(x_test)
      accuracy = dtc.score(x_train,y_train)
      Prd.append(i)
      Prdacc.append(accuracy)
      print(accuracy)
      pickle.dump(dtc, open( 'model'+'/'+str(i)+'mod.pkl',"wb"))
      pickle.dump(scaler, open( 'model'+'/'+str(i)+'scl.pkl',"wb"))
   except:
      pass
```

Comment: Your loop does iterate 19 times from what it seems to me. You're not breaking out of the loop or anything so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Maybe you're getting an exception on the other iterations? Print the exception instead of hiding it with `pass`.

Comment: @Jab I found out the Error It was iterating only once due to following: I updated the df_results on the first itteration at df_reults = df_results[df_results['Product'] == i]

Comment: It's still iterating 19 times, just not updating anything.

Comment: @Jab  yup it did iterate, just did not have the the products in them as the df_result updated it self with product 1 in first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a mistake I ignored due to lack of attention. The df_results gets update on the first iteration.

```
df_result = df_result[df_result['Product'] == i]
   x = df_result[feature_colsx]
   y = df_result[feature_colsy]
```

So, the code should rather be:

```
df_temp = df_result[df_result['Product'] == i]
   x = df_temp[feature_colsx]
   y = df_temp[feature_colsy]
```